# Defining a range of symbols whose bounds are OTHER symbols

Tags: python, math, sympy

I'm trying to express a summation over an arbitrary (but finite) number of symbols, which I wish to be given by another symbol. For instance, is it possible to say:

```
N,ci,cj = symbols('N,c_i,c_j')
# pseudocode
k = sum(ci+cj,(ci,0,N),(cj,0,N))
```

or, more literally,

```
k = sum(ci+cj, (ci != cj))
```

My instinct is that it isn't, but I do wish sympy would implement support for it!

**UPDATE**

It appears sympy offers provisions for indexed variables. Namely:

```
x = IndexedBase('x')
i,j = symbols('i j',cls=Idx)
```

however, the you can an error when attempting:

```
y = Sum(x[i], (i, 0, 2))
```

Which is:

```
ValueError: Invalid limits given: ((i, 1, 5),)
```

Comment: Yes, instances of ``Indexed`` needs to be supported in ``Sum``, I ran into the problem myself but haven't gotten around fixing it. It is "just" a matter of patching the sympy code base and sending a PR. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Function, like `x = symbols('x', cls=Function)` and `x(i)`. Indexed should also work, but it looks like Sum has a bug that disallows `Idx`. It works if you just use `i = symbols('i')`, though.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I ended up doing.